# Assigning a variable conditionally inside a SELECT statement on SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

I am attempting to write a `SELECT` statement on SQL Server that displays items based on a condition, which I provide in the subsequent `WHERE` clause.

Here is a simplified version of what I am attempting to write.

```
DECLARE @tmpvar varchar(5)
....

SELECT @tmpvar,
....
FROM some_table
WHERE 
....
and @tmpvar =
      CASE WHEN (some condition here)
             THEN 'YES'
             ELSE 'NO'
      END
```

The code above executes successfully, but when I check the value of `@tmpvar`, it remains unassigned.

I'd like to know if there is a mistake in the syntax I am using. If so, what would be the correct way of assigning the variable inside the `SELECT` statement using the given condition? Prior apologies if this question is redundant.

Comment: In this query you DON'T assign variable you just use its value (NULL I guess). For example if @tmpvar='1' then it is equivalent `SELECT '1',
....
FROM some_table
WHERE 
....
and '1' =
      CASE WHEN (some condition here)
             THEN 'YES'
             ELSE 'NO'
      END`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't assign in the `WHERE` clause. You can in the [`SELECT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187330.aspx) clause:

```
DECLARE @tmpvar varchar(5)
....

SELECT @tmpvar =
      CASE WHEN (some condition here)
             THEN 'YES'
             ELSE 'NO'
      END,
....
FROM some_table
WHERE 
....
```

But only if you're not also attempting data retrieval at the same time. Also, it's pretty poorly defined which row(s) will influence the result if there's more than 1 row in the result set, unless you have an `ORDER BY` clause:

> If the SELECT statement returns more than one value, the variable is assigned the last value that is returned.

---

As you may have noticed, SQL uses `=` for assignment, comparison and introducing aliases. Which one is determined by the position that the `=` appears in. In the `WHERE` clause, `=` can only be comparison.

Comment: is it possible to assign a variable at the same time of retrieving data?

Comment: @Kailegh - no, you cannot [`SELECT @local_variable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/select-local-variable-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#remarks) - "A SELECT statement that contains a variable assignment cannot be used to also perform typical result set retrieval operations."